# Possible to mock fields annotated with @Context in JMockit?

Tags: java, jmockit

I have the following field in a class under test:

```
class ClassUnderTest {

  @Context
  public javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext securityContext;

  public void someMethod() {
    securityContext.getUserPrinciple(); // securityContext is always null here - never mocked
  }
}
```

But I cannot get JMockit to mock it using expectations or the MockUp approach, in both cases in the class under test securityContext is always null?

```
@Test
public void usingExpectations() {
  new Expectations() {
    @Mocked
    SecurityContext mockSecurityContext;
    @Mocked
    Principal mockPrinciple;
    {
      mockSecurityContext.getUserPrincipal();
      result = mockPrinciple;

      mockPrinciple.getName();
      result = username;
     }
  };

  new ClassUnderTest().someMethod();
}

@Test
public using usingMockUp() {
  new MockUp<SecurityContext>() {
    @Mock
    Principle getUserPrincipal() {
      // return something   
    };
  }
  new ClassUnderTest().someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is not doing anything to have the `securityContext` field set, so it remains null.

JMockit has features for that, though. You can either set the field explicitly by calling `Deencapsulation.setField(...)`, or let JMockit do it automatically by using the `@Tested` and `@Injectable` annotations. For details and examples, please check the [documentation](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#tested).